# AWS Cognito UserPool - Turn list of IDs into list of User attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working with an AWS Cognito UserPool.

I have a list of Cognito User IDs. I'm interested in querying Cognito for attributes for each ID. I see that Cognito supports querying one ID at a time, but doesn't support batch queries. Is this the case?

Is there a performant way to convert a list of IDs into a list of objects with user attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito doesn't support batch get-user queries, so you are basically left with 2 options.

1. If the user pool is not very large, use [`ListUsers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) API to dump all user info. Max batch size is 60.
2. If your user pool is huge, use multi-threading/processing to fetch users in parallel.

Comment: Bummer, that's super unfortunate.